# Running executables on an NTFS partition?

Tags: permissions, windows, ntfs

My system configuration is the following:

- UEFI computer
- Dual-boot with Windows 8 and Linux Mint 15 Olivia

I would like to be able to run Linux executables that are stored on an NTFS partition rather than having to copy them each time on a Linux partition.

Whenever ticking the *Execute* check box it de-ticks itself, I guess because it's on an NTFS partition.

[image]

I've come across this post:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Searching on my system, I have found that mentioned settings can be done in *Disks* settings dialog:

[image]

I thought about appending *exec* at the end of default parameters but I'm not sure about these things:

- According to answer 2 of the above question: *NTFS is a POSIX-compatible* and *To enable this, you need a "User Mapping File"*.
- So, is the *User Mapping File* a file stored on the Linux partition? (i.e. stores Linux-specific permissions in my Linux partition instead of directly changing the permissions in the  NTFS partition).

**In short :**

Can I safely do this as I will still use my Windows with this partition?

Comment: This sounds like what you're asking about: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/. I have no experience with this however. I think @deroberts is our resident NTFS samba guy wrt. this type of stuff. Stephane might know about this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding exec while nosuid is set is relatively safe (comparable to a native home-directory on a linux-system).

Unsafe would be suid and exec.

And no - you should not need a user-mapping for this.
You are already mapping to user and group aybe.