# chmod not working on NTFS-3g partition

Tags: permissions, chmod, ntfs-3g

I have a file on an NTFS-3g partition, I tried using `chmod` to add execute to this file, but it remained unchanged.

What am I doing wrong? I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99477/running-executables-on-an-ntfs-partition) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) posts, but none of them worked, this is my fstable

```
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=113A2F5635174B03   /media/data ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,uid=1000,gid=users,dmask=022,fmask=133,utf8    0   0
```

Comment: I think your fmask is likely wrong, both in decimal and octal.

Comment: `dmask` and `fmask` render `chmod` useless.

Comment: @user10489, thanks so much for this tip, that's it, it's solved my problem

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thanks for this tip, I removed fmask & dmask from fstab, and made it auto, now the permission for every file is 777, tried to change to 755, still nor working, is it because the drive is NTFS-3g?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user10489, just adjust fmask and dmask according to your needs, a full explanation can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options).